# AutoMapper + EF Core: Query where nested property equals value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

Seems like a simple one but I couldn't get the following query to execute with EF core.

```
public class ParentThing // EF entity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int? ChildThingId { get; set; }
   public ChildThing Child { get; set ; }
}

public class ChildThing // EF entity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDTO 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ParentDTO
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public ChildDTO Child { get; set; }
}

public static void Run(int id, DbSet<ParentThing> dbSet, IMapper mapper)
{
   // mappings are something like this...
   // CreateMap<ChildThing, ChildDTO>();
   // CreateMap<ParentThing, ParentDTO>();

   var dtos = mapper.ProjectTo<ParentDTO>(dbSet)
               .Where(e => e.Child.Id == id) // this throws an exception
               .ToList();
}
```

I get the following exception when trying to execute the query.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'.
```

I tried converting the queried id to a nullable int and got the following exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Rewriting child expression from type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' is not allowed, because it would change the meaning of the operation. If this is intentional, override 'VisitUnary' and change it to allow this rewrite.
```

Do I really need to flatten out the nested properties in order to query them?

Comment: Try updating EF Core. Also the filter must be before the `ProjectTo`.

Comment: Did you try this   .Where(e =>  e.Child!=null  &&  e.Child.Id == id)

Comment: checking for a null object first still threw an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Rewriting child expression from type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' is not allowed, because it would change the meaning of the operation. If this is intentional, override 'VisitUnary' and change it to allow this rewrite.

Comment: Filtering the dbSet prior to calling ProjectTo does appear to work although feels a bit clunky. I'll take a look at the underlying query string and see how complicated it makes it.

Comment: Did you try the same query without mapping? It could help to find the exception source

Comment: The example I presented is a much simpler version of the actual situation and the DTOs are much easer to use. The error is getting thrown because ParentThing records has no child and the null reference is behind the exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I really need to flatten out the nested properties in order to query them?

Looks like you need to.

The whole question is whether the "child" reference can be `null` or not (i.e. optional or required).

If it is optional, there is no other solution than flattening the reference object properties and making them nullable. Or apply the filter on the entity query before the projection. This is because EF Core handles navigation properties differently (and better) than projections. What AutoMapper is doing is equivalent of something like

```cs
db.Set<ParentThing>()
    .Select(p => new ParentDto
    {
        // ...
        Child = p.ChildThing == null ? null : new ChildDto { ... })
    }
    .Where(...);
```

The error you are getting is because of the conditional construct. But if you don't use it, then you'll get different exception when the data is null.

So, a clean solution is *only* possible when the reference is required. In that case, all you need is to let AutoMapper eliminate the null check and generate directly `Child = new ChildDto { ... }`. Which can be specified with `DoNotAllowNull`, e.g.

```cs
CreateMap<ParentThing, ParentDTO>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Child, opt => opt.DoNotAllowNull());
```

But again, this works only for required references.

Comment: @Lucian I know you are one of AM main contributors. But... I always test the things before posting. `DoNotAllowNull` (or `AllowNullDestinationValues = false`) is what eliminates the `null` check in projection.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, sorry, those names don't help much I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using

```
public ChildThing Child { get; set ; }
```

it can confuse entity framework

So I think to create explicit navigaion properties could help

```
public class ParentThing // EF entity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int? ChildThingId { get; set; }
   public ChildThing ChildThing { get; set ; }
}

public class ChildThing // EF entity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ParentThing ParentThing { get; set ; }
}
```

I am wondering if your DbSet<> includes Child, it can be null and it could cause an exception. But in this case you can use this code

```
 var parents=  dbSet
         .Where(e => e.ChildThingId!=null && ( (int) e.ChildThingId ) == id)
         .ToList();

 var dtos = mapper.Map<List<ParentThing>, List<ParentDto>>(parents);
```

Comment: I've clarified the ParentThing class in the original post. The navigation property existed but I forgot to include it in the example. It makes it so I can filter prior to ProjectTo but wondering if there a way to filter after ProjectTo

Comment: @WaitsAtWork I told you about child is null before.  Have you tried ChildThingId==id ?

Comment: I did and it works as a work-around. If that's the only way then I'll close the issue.